# Executing a Python script from Drupal

Tags: files

I'm trying to execute a python script from Drupal using this:

```csh
exec('/usr/bin/python name_of_the_script.py')
```

But it does not work. Although, if I'm on the php console (`php -a`), then it works fine.

The `name_of_the_script.py` file has all the permissions.

I thought maybe it was the `python` command that didn't have all the permissions.

So I checked it with this command:

```csh
which python
ls -lisa /usr/bin/python
```

> **694 0 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 2011-03-09 18:41 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6**

Similarly I also used this command:

```csh
ls -lisa /usr/bin/python2.6
```

> **369 2240 -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2288240 2010-04-16 10:06 /usr/bin/python2.6**

It seems everything is OK.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Executing an external script in Drupal is not different from executing it from PHP, as Drupal doesn't have specific functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **2>&1**

```
exec('/usr/bin/python script.py 2>&1');
```

Pointed me to the right direction.

I was writting in a file ( inside the script that hadn't enough permissions )

chmod 666 name_of_the_file.txt totally solved the issue!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it's a permission of your webserver that is causing this. You should take care  as things could turn out badly should your drupal site be compromised.